# Browser that does refactoring in Smalltalk Pharo?

Tags: browser, smalltalk, pharo

The Pharo dev image ships, by default, with a browser that doesn't seem to have any refactoring abilities. What's the most convenient way to transform a fresh Pharo image into something more useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You either download the [Pharo Developer Image](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26681/Pharo-1.0-10515-rc3dev10.03.1.zip) from the download section on the [Pharo Website](http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download) (it contains a selection of developer tools including the refactoring engine) or you use the following script in a [Pharo Core Image](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26668/PharoCore-1.0-10515rc3.zip):

```
"Refactoring"
Gofer new
    squeaksource: 'rb';
    package: 'AST-Core';
    package: 'Refactoring-Core';
    package: 'Refactoring-Spelling';
    load.

"OmniBrowser"
Gofer new
    renggli: 'omnibrowser';
    package: 'OmniBrowser';
    package: 'OB-Standard';
    package: 'OB-Morphic';
    package: 'OB-Shout';
    package: 'OB-Refactory';
    package: 'OB-Regex';
    package: 'OB-SUnitIntegration';
    load.

"Tools"
Gofer new
    renggli: 'unsorted';
    package: 'Shout';
    package: 'RoelTyper';
    package: 'ECompletion';
    package: 'ECompletionOmniBrowser';
    load.

"Select Tools"
SystemBrowser default: (Smalltalk at: #OBSystemBrowserAdaptor).
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you tell me *exactly* which Pharo image did you download ? because refactoring tools, and several other developer tools are shipped by default in the Pharo images.

Check the following link: http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/26681/Pharo-1.0-10515-rc3dev10.03.1.zip

that I got from http://www.pharo-project.org/pharo-download

Thanks

Comment: I think I downloaded a dev image the pharo website.

Comment: from Pharo 2.0 on, Refactoring tools are available again. A complete list of images can be found at http://pharo.gforge.inria.fr/ci/image